# Does enunciate support generating C# clients for REST-based interfaces?

Tags: c#, rest, jax-rs, enunciate

I've got a project with some REST-based interfaces and would like to generate C# code for them. Can enunciate help me doing this or is it only for WS* interfaces?

Running enunciate in the debug mode using `mvn -X` I can see message:

```
[DEBUG] [csharp] C# module is disabled because there are no endpoint interfaces, nor any XML types
```

Do you know any other tools that could be used for that?

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Enunciate doesn't generate REST clients yet. [It's been requested, though](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-760).